# Simplest way to read a file using jcifs

Tags: java, jcifs

I am trying to read a file from a network share using the external [jcifs library](https://jcifs.samba.org/). Most sample codes I can find for reading files are quite complex, potentially unnecessarily so. I have found a simple way to *write* to a file as seen below. Is there a way to read a file using similar syntax?

```
SmbFile file= null;
try {
    String url = "smb://"+serverAddress+"/"+sharename+"/TEST.txt";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, username, password);
    file = new SmbFile(url, auth);
    SmbFileOutputStream out= new SmbFileOutputStream(file);
    out.write("test string".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: "+e);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use SmbFileInputStream in a simillar fashion?

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek Probably. How does one do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SmbFile file = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try {
    String url = "smb://"+serverAddress+"/"+sharename+"/TEST.txt";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, username, password);
    file = new SmbFile(url, auth);
    try (SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream(file)) {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do {
            bytesRead = in.read(buffer)
            // here you have "bytesRead" in buffer array
        } 
        while (bytesRead > 0);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: "+e);
}
```

or even better, assuming that you're working with text files - using `BufferedReader` from Java SDK:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new SmbFileInputStream(file)))) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
```

And write with:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new SmbFileOutputStream(file)))) {
    String toWrite = "xxxxx";
    writer.write(toWrite, 0, toWrite.length());
}
```

Comment: oooh, +1 for the bufferedreader implementation. Was unaware you could do that

Comment: How do I write a new line using the bufferedwriter solution? Currently If I loop the method the output to file is onetwothreefour. I would like each element on a seperate line.

Answer (score 8):

```
    try {
        String url = "smb://" + serverAddress + "/" + sharename + "/test.txt";
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(DOMAIN, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
        String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(new SmbFileInputStream(new SmbFile(url, auth)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        System.out.println(fileContent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I could read some pdf files using this:

```
    private final Singleton<CIFSContext> contextoDdetran = new Singleton<>() {
        @Override
        public CIFSContext inicializar() {
            NtlmPasswordAuthenticator autenticador = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator(smbDomain, smbUser, smbPassword);
            return SingletonContext.getInstance().withCredentials(autenticador);
        }
    };

    public byte[] readSmbFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            SmbFile file = new SmbFile(fileName, this.contextoDdetran.get());
            return file.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            final String msgErro = String.format("Error reading file '%s': %s", fileName, e.getMessage());
            logger.error(msgErro, e);
            throw new IllegalStateException(msgErro);
        }
    }
```