# Files.exists() returning false when run on Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, file, nio

I have a program which checks if the given file is present on Windows Shared location.
I am using java.nio.file.Files.exists() for this purpose.
Following is my code

```
String strFilePath = "\\\\ftc-bqeutil\\logs\\Software\\Acc\\Admin\\xml_with_diff.xml";
if (Files.exists(path)) {
            System.out.println("File exist");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
```

This code works fine on Windows machine and prints files exist. But on Linux it is not working. On Linux it prints "File does not exist"
Note : File is present at the given location and it has all the access rights.
I also tried changing file location as

```
String strFilePath = "smb://ftc-bqeutil/logs/Software/Acc/Admin/xml_with_diff.xml";
```

But it is not working. Can you help me?

Comment: `smb://...` is not an acceptable file path scheme on *nixes.

Comment: You say the file exists on Linux. Can you show an `ls` command that shows it exists?

Comment: smb it seems a network share files, you cannot check by Files.exists. check how to read smb here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487647/simplest-way-to-read-a-file-using-jcifs

Comment: Also, avoid using backspaces as a path separator. If you specify a path in a Java string literal, use `/` or even `File.separator`. Java will then use the separator matching the underlying OS conventions.

Comment: @mumpitz Do you mean back*slashes*?  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle sorry, yes, of course :) Unfortunately i can't edit that anymore...